# Alternatives to str.split() in Python 3 when interacting with a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I'm currently playing around with making a file duplicator in Python. It currently works on its own when I customise the number of duplications in the actual program, but I am working on making a separate and basic setup file. This will allow you to specify the number of duplicates you want.

At the moment, this number is saved onto a plain text document in list form. So the document can look like
    [0, 1, 2, 3]
to 
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
depending on what you put in.

The problem is that when the actual duplicator program tries to get the list from the plain text file, it interprets it as a string, so it looks like

```
count = ['[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]']
```

I have searched the internet far and wide for a solution to this, but the only solution I can find is to use str.split(). From my knowledge, this was removed in Python 3. Are there any alternatives that I can employ in this situation?

Here is the code for the actual duplicator:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shutil
import getpass
data = open("/Volumes/USB/Data.txt", "r")
username = getpass.getuser()
count = data.readlines(1)
print(str(count))
for x in count:
    shutil.copy2('/Volumes/USB/img.jpg', 'img{0}.jpg'.format(x))
    print(str(count))
```

And here is the code for the setup file:

```
import time
import fileinput
with open("/Volumes/USB/Data,txt", "r") as f:
# Precount is where the original list will go to let them know how many have previously been selected. I will convert this to the number of entries in the list eventually.
    precount = list(f.readlines(1))
    print('Enter the desired amount of images. Your current amount is {0}.'.format(precount))
countbase = input()
count = [0]
n = 1
while int(n) < int(countbase):
    list.append(count, n)
    n += 1
with open("/Volumes/USB/Data.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str((count)))
print('Configuration complete!')
time.sleep(1)
quit()
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: "but the only solution I can find is to use str.split(). From my knowledge, this was removed in Python 3" the `.split` method was not removed.

Comment: Your setup file should probably just be JSON, since that is already supported.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be happier with `next(data)`,
but what you have currently is a very short list
returned by `.readlines(1)`.

If you take the initial list element you'll just have a string:

```
count[0]
```

You can pass that to a JSON parser to turn the string into a list of integers:

```
import json
counts = json.loads(count[0])
```

Then you can iterate over those `int`s to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

The first, and simplest, would be to use the `ast` module to parse the input:

```
import ast

ast.literal_eval('[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]')
```

This produces the `list` object `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

If you foresee adding more options, it would probably be better to store your configuration data in JSON format. You can use the functions in the `json` module for that (in particular, `json.dump` and `json.load`).

Lastly, you could use the `pickle` module to save your configuration in binary format. I wouldn't recommend this, because `pickle` allows arbitrary code execution.